# I am trying to share a post on Facebook and WhatsApp only

Tags: react-native

is there any way to limit platforms for sharing on social media in expo, for example, I want to share only one Facebook and WhatsApp and don't show other platforms on the dialogue box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the official dependencies `react-native-share`
here's the link :- https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share

These can be assessed using Share.Social property For eg.

```
import Share from 'react-native-share';

const shareOptions = {
    title: 'Share via',
    message: 'some message',
    url: 'some share url',
    social: Share.Social.WHATSAPP,
    whatsAppNumber: "9199999999",  // country code + phone number(currently only works             on Android)
    filename: 'test' , // only for base64 file in Android 
};
Share.shareSingle(shareOptions);
```

if you have any problem then feel free to ask me.

Thank You.